# Passing parameter of C# DateTime to SQL Server 2005?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, datetime

How do I pass C# `DateTime` values (`FromCreateDate` and `ToCreateDate`) to SQL Server 2005 in order to select from a view ?

The result set `CreateDate` column must be between `FromDateDate` and `ToCreateDate`.

Comment: Well, It's ratherly a puzzled situation: I would like to make a report in a way that if my user entered a date for FromCreateDate then I compare it to createDate column, if not, then I compare createdate column only with ToCreateDate value (i.e. <=ToCreateDate)

Comment: then you need something like: `WHERE createDate >= @fromDate AND (@toDate IS NULL OR createDate <= @toDate)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly the same as you would any other parameter... of course it depends on how you are doing your data-access, but if we assume a `SqlCommand` you'd just refer to a named parameter (`@fromDate` / `@toDate`) in the TSQL, and add named `SqlParameter`s (with `.Value = theDate`) to the command:

```
DateTime end = DateTime.Today, start = end.AddDays(-7); // the last week
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", start); // fine for DateTime; for strings, use more explicit param
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", end); // construction to avoid lots of different-length plans
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [Users] WHERE LastSeen >= @from AND LastSeen < @to";
    int count = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

With LINQ etc you'd just use it in the query, i.e.

```
int count = db.Users.Count(user => user.LastSeen>=start && user.LastSeen<end);
```

I'm using a simple count in the examples just to keep it simple; obviously you can `SELECT blah` from a `VIEW` etc too...

Comment: @Mark: Do I must send two values as string and then convert them into datetime in stored procedure ?

Comment: No; just set your `DateTime` variables into `yourParameter.Value`. I'll add an example...

Answer (score 8):

Just set the parameter type to `SqlDbType.DateTime`

e.g

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * From dbo.MyView Where createDate = @FromDate", SqlCon);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@FromDate, SqlDbType.DateTime));
cmd.Parameters["@FromDate"].Value = fromDate;
```